# Using vim for git commit messages broken after updating janus

Tags: macos, git, vim

After updating the janus vim distribution there appears to be a problem with using vim for commit messages. The best example of this is when doing a `git pull` to get someone else's changes. The vim editor is displayed, I type my commit message, I enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> but instead of the commit working, I get the following error message:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

I then have to manually commit :(

How do I get git to play nicely with vim?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

After a bit of googling, it turns out that the answer is to run the following:

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```

Comment: [Relevant read tooky.co.uk/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x/](http://tooky.co.uk/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 11):

Nat Ritmeyer has given the [right solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607585/117471). I will give you the cause.

As [Steve Tooke explained](http://tooky.co.uk/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x/), hiding your `~/.vimrc` or explicitly telling `git` to use the complete path to `vim` solves the problem. However, he ends with *"I’d still like to get to the root of the problem"*.

Try this:

1. Start a `git commit` to get yourself into a `vim` editor.
2. Hit `<CTRL> + Z` to stop the process and drop back to the TTY
3. Do a `ps` and notice for your TTY (whose number you get with the `tty` command) there is something like...

   ```
   $ tty
   /dev/ttys005

   $ ps
     PID TTY           TIME CMD
   17547 ttys005    0:00.15 -bash
   65126 ttys005    0:00.02 git commit
   65127 ttys005    0:00.10 vi .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

   $ which vi
   /usr/bin/vi

   $ ll /usr/bin/vi
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3 Oct  3 17:40 /usr/bin/vi -> vim

   $ jobs
   [1]+  Stopped                 git commit
   ```
4. Get back to your vim process with `fg %1` (or what ever stopped job number your `git commit` is listed as).

What that shell output tells us is...

1. I was using ttys005
2. On the TTY `bash` called `git` and `git` called `vi`
3. The full path of `vi` is `/usr/bin/vi`
4. The `vi` command is a symlink to `vim`
5. Calling `<CTRL> + Z` stopped the `git commit` command and it was #1 in the job stack.

So, **vi is the same command as vim?!?!** Yes, but `vim` notices that its `argv[0]` was `vi` and runs in [compatible mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#compatible-default). This can cause problems depending on what is in your `.vimrc`.

The **best solution** is to tell git to use vim, but I suggest you **don't assume** that your vim path is the same as everyone elses (maybe you installed via `brew install vim`)

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```

Answer (score 5):

This could be a plugin or something in your .vimrc file. The best way to load vim in a safe mode for editing commit messages is to use:

```
git config --global core.editor '/usr/bin/vim -f -u NONE'
```

Comment: for an explanation, see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vim-arguments
[Mr Wilde](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1009774/mr-wilde) is suggesting running `vim` in the "foreground", staying attached to the git process, and without a `vimrc` config file (no plugins)
This did fix the issue I came here for, but introduced others, since this results in a *very* limited form of `vim`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem every time I fetched from remote repo and merged it with another branch.

Typing this in terminal fixed it for me

`git config --global core.editor $(which vim)`

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, `git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim` doesn't work, try without the `--global` flag. I could get it to work only without the `--global` flag.