# git commit not saving after :Wq

Tags: git, vim

Sometimes when I'm committing something in git, I accidentally hit :Wq to save my changes. (note the capital letter W)
Then vim complains that :Wq 'is not an editor command'

Then I correctly use :wq to save and quit. Then it does quit, but no commit is made and I have to redo the commit process. I also have to rewrite my commit message as it is also lost.

Also, when I do :w and :q separately after I made the capital :Wq mistake, the outcome is the same. Although vim does say that the changes have been written when using the :w command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using vim for git commit messages broken after updating janus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607584/using-vim-for-git-commit-messages-broken-after-updating-janus)

Comment: Solution is the same, although my problem scenario is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. To solve it, run the following command.

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```